# Inject into head section of html page using PHP

Tags: php, html

Anytime I `echo` something out in PHP, no matter where the PHP code sits it puts the generated code into the `body` tag of the html page.

**How do I inject html created by PHP into the `head` tag of the HTML?**

for example making the title dynamic or writing a script within the head dynamic.

example code:

```
<html>
  <head>
    <?php echo "moo"; ?>
  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>
```

returns:

```
<html>
  <head>
  </head>
  <body>
    moo
  </body>
</html>
```

**EDIT:**

I am running it through the server running Nagios this might have something to do with it.

Comment: jQuery is usually a wildly inappropriate tool to suggest as the solution to almost any question that is asking how to do something with a server side language.

Comment: Re update: Cannot reproduce. Running that code gives this output (line breaks lost due to SOs comment formatting): `<html>
  <head>
    moo  </head>
  <body>
  </body>
</html>`

Comment: Your example [works fine](http://ideone.com/3ZN0x).  Do you, by chance, have output buffering on?

Comment: @Nayish: http://ideone.com/3ZN0x

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is happening because you can only have specific tags in your `<head>`.

You cannot have text nodes (such as "moo") in your `<head>`.  The PHP is outputting correctly, but the browser is trying to correct the malformed HTML.

More info: https://developer.mozilla.org/en/HTML/Element/head

> Elements that can be used inside a `<head>` element: `<title>`, `<base>`, `<link>`, `<style>`, `<meta>`, `<script>`, `<noscript>`, `<command>`

Comment: Yes, that would be my assumption. Browsers always try to fix broken HTML before rendering. @Nayish, how are you examining the resulting code? "View Source", or the browser's "live" display of the output HTML? I'd suspect they're different, in this case.

Answer (score 0):

Unless you are dealing with a DOM or other structured data (which you aren't since you are using `echo`) then as far as PHP is concerned you are just outputting text.

You need to place your echo statement somewhere after the code that causes your program to output `<head>` and somewhere before it outputs `</head>`.

This:

> no matter where the PHP code sits it puts the generated code into the body tag of the html page

… can't be the case. You just haven't found the point in your code that you care about.

(Since we can't see the code, we can't find it for you).

Comment: @Nayish — And it doesn't give the output you say it gives.

Answer (score 0):

```
<head>
<?php echo $htmlCreatedByPHP;?>
</head>
```

The following elements can go inside the `<head>` element:

```
<title>
<style>
<base>
<link>
<meta>
<script>
<noscript>
```

So what are you trying to achieve ?
http://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_head.asp

Answer (score 0):

You can surely do it in PHP, for sure, you are using some `framework/CMS`, which is outputting everything in its body tag. So in that case, you need to check the templating section of your `framework/CMS`, which contains the key to modifying things in your `head tag` files.

Comment: and what are you using the see the source code? firebug? or source directly? I prefer you to check the source without a firebug. If you are checking the source correctly, then what you have put is impossible in pure PHP!!